# What can I use (instead of jupiter) to control the Super Hybrid Engine on my eeepc 1015T

Tags: 13.10, eeepc, jupiter

I'm running Saucy on my EEEpc. For a while there was this great tool called `jupiter` which handled a lot of the power management and CPU scaling on eeepcs. Unfortunately, the tool went out of development this summer and has been incompatible with the new version of ubuntu. Battery life has been pretty bad with the new version of ubuntu, so is there a way to get all of these power saving functions working with the newest ubuntu version?

Comment: I'd like to know this too! The super hybrid engine was so good. I have searched but not found any information to say there is anything to replace Jupiter. Would someone out there like to write a program so the super hybrid engine can be used?